# Divide by Zero error in Sklearn Optics clustering

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Was trying to use OPTICS to segment my data.

```
from sklearn.cluster import OPTICS
X_scaler = StandardScaler().fit(X)
X_final = X_scaler.transform(X)
opt = OPTICS()
opt.fit(X_final)
```

However, there seems to be some error in getting reachability plot when extracting clusters using Xi-steep method

```
C:\Users\d11\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\cluster\optics_.py:791: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in true_divide
  ratio = reachability_plot[:-1] / reachability_plot[1:]
```

I tried changing xi from 0.05 to 0.5 and min_samples but to no avail. Please help!

Comment: For others coming here: this error may be caused by feature vectors being non-unique (i.e. X having duplicate entries).

Answer (score 4):

**This is just a warning not an error**. If you want to avoid this, you can try one these.

1. First option

```
import numpy as np
with np.errstate(divide='ignore'):
    ratio = reachability_plot[:-1] / reachability_plot[1:]
```

2. Second Option

```
import numpy as np
np.seterr(divide='ignore', invalid='ignore')
ratio = reachability_plot[:-1] / reachability_plot[1:]
```